# Login in Active Directory Domain (Samba 4) and mount -t cifs on debian

Tags: active-directory, samba, kerberos, samba4, sssd

I've configured Samba 4 with bind and kerberos to work as an Active Directory authentication server. I've also configured "home share" so I can login to any Windows machine in my Domain and work with my files.

In addition I want to access my files on Debian Desktop. I've installed realmd and sssd on Debian Desktop and I am able to login in my Domain. But when I'm trying to mount my files using:

```
mount -t cifs -o user=szymon //192.168.1.1/netlogon/szymon files/
```

I have problem with proper uid and gid mapping. Result of ls -l:

```
drwxrwx---+ 13 3000000 users 0 lis 5 11:49 files
-rwxr-xr-x 1 szymon@hogwart.local domain users@hogwart.local 79 lis 5 14:14 wfmount
```

I even cannot cd into files/.

How can I setup Samba 4 to mount my Share with correct permissions?

Answer (score 0):

Your linux client needs a way to translate AD users to unix users.

This is usually done by the `winbindd` service, which is a part of the samba4 suite (to be installed and configured on the client).